# How to filter select2 dropdown with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, metronic

I have used [select2](https://select2.github.io/) type dropdown and bind with **value-text** pairs and it's doing filter properly based on **(tenancyname) text** as per below.

```
<li class="dropdown" id="liTenancy" style="margin-top: 4px; min-width: 250px !important;">                           
                        <select class="form-control select2me" data-placeholder="Select..." style="white-space: nowrap;">


                                    @foreach (var Tenancy in Entity)
                                    {
                                        <option @(SelectedTenancy == Tenancy.TenancyId ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") value="@Tenancy.TenancyId">
                                            <a class="optionTenancy" href="javascript:void(0);" id="@Tenancy.TenancyId">@Tenancy.TenancyName</a>
                                        </option>
                                    }
                        </select>
                    </li>
```

Now i would like to filter this list with **tenancyname (text) or tenancyid (value)** (user can user both to filter list) then how can i customize js without doing it with remote call??

Comment: Select2 supports a custom `matcher` which is what you are looking for. And this has a duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks kevin for your suggestion, I found my solution as below which can be helpful to any other user

I have put id in value attribute and guid in alt attribute in option tag and use custom matcher as below

```
$('select.select2me').select2({
                placeholder: "Select",
                allowClear: true,                
                matcher: function (term, text, opt) {
                    return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) >= 0
                    || opt.attr("alt").toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) >= 0
                    || opt.attr("value").toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
                }
            });
```